# Testing Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using Two GraphQL APIs one for data and one for content. Hence using below code to enable this based on https://www.jamalx31.com/tech-posts/using-apollo-with-multiple-graphql-endpoints

```
import { HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';

let apolloClientInstance: ApolloClient<unknown> | null = null;

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

const createApolloClient = (
    initialState = {},
    headers?: IncomingHttpHeaders
) => {
    const gqlAPI1 = new HttpLink({
        uri: publicRuntimeConfig.GRAPHQL_API,
        credentials: 'include',
        fetch,
        headers: { 'key': '1234' }
    });

    const gqlAPI2 = new HttpLink({
        uri: API2_URL,
        fetch,
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
            'Content-Language': 'en-us'
        }
    });

    return new ApolloClient({
        link: ApolloLink.split(
            (operation) => operation.getContext().clientName === 'cms',
            gqlAPI2,
            gqlAPI1
        ),
        cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState)
    });

};
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this as mentioned below.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
import React from 'react';
jest.mock('next-with-apollo');
jest.mock('apollo-boost');
jest.mock('@apollo/react-hooks');
jest.mock('isomorphic-unfetch');
import ApolloClient, {
    ApolloLink,
    HttpLink,
    InMemoryCache
} from 'apollo-boost';
import nextWithApollo from 'next-with-apollo';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

const mockInMemoryCache = {
    restore: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mockInMemoryCache')
};
(InMemoryCache as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(mockInMemoryCache);

jest.requireActual('../../shared/graphql/withApollo');

    describe('client', () => {
    const client = (nextWithApollo as jest.Mock).mock.calls[0][0];

        it('is configured just the way we want it', () => {
            const gqlAPI1 = new HttpLink({
                uri: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/graphql',
                credentials: 'include',
                fetch,
                headers: { 'key': '1234' }
            });
        
            const gqlAPI2 = new HttpLink({
                uri: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/',
                fetch,
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bearer sadsdasdasdsadsa`,
                    'Content-Language': 'en-us'
                }
            });

            const link = ApolloLink.split(
                (operation) => operation.getContext().clientName === 'cms',
                gqlAPI2,
                gqlAPI1
            );

            expect(ApolloClient).not.toBeCalled();
            client({});
            expect(ApolloClient).toBeCalledWith({ 
                link: link,
                cache: 'mockInMemoryCache'
            });
        });
});
```

I am getting below error

```
  ● Apollo provider › client › is configured just the way we want it

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"cache": "mockInMemoryCache", "link": undefined}

    Number of calls: 0

      67 |             expect(ApolloClient).not.toBeCalled();
      68 |             client({});
    > 69 |             expect(ApolloClient).toBeCalledWith({ 
         |                                  ^
      70 |                 link: link,
      71 |                 cache: 'mockInMemoryCache' 
      72 |             })
```

I am unable to find out the issue, I can see the `"link": undefined` but again not sure why it comes like this. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the import/require code for each module

Comment: @slideshowp2 - Added thanks :-)